# Replacing IDs using a list full of duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, mapping

Here is my problem. Basically, I have a dataframe with a lot of comparisons.
When value = 0, it means we are in front of the same observation with the same values in each feature. I want to replace those IDs IN THE ORIGINAL DATAFRAME so that I have only one ID for the same observation.
My idea was to create a dictionary or list with all the values similar to each other, but the problem of my DF is that if I have (idA = 1, idB = 2, value = 0), I also have one row with idA and idB swapped (idA = 1, idB = 2, value = 0).
For example, I'd like to replace the IDs (49923-19848-22162-14780-13689) and the Ids (23549-47291-2576) with just one ID, but since there's a duplication problem I'm not sure how to do that.

Basically this is my df

```
    index   idA     idB     Value   
    3       49923   19848   0.0     
    28899   14780   49923   0.0     
    31470   49923   13689   0.0     
    44702   22162   49923   0.0     
    21125   19848   22162   0.0     
    31760   14780   19848   0.0     
    38533   13689   19848   0.0     
    5       23549   47291   0.0     
    7665    28527   23549   0.0     
    23574   2576    23549   0.0     
    40879   28527   47291   0.0     
    41209   2576    47291   0.0
```

I would like to create a new dictionary like:

d = {49923:(19848, 22162, 14780, 13689), 23549:(47291, 2576) }

So that I can replace the IDs in the list as value using the key.
For example, I'd like that IDs  19848, 22162, 14780, 13689 become ID 49923.
Actually, ID numeration is not important at all, I want just a way to find which are the identical rows and replace their IDs in the original dataframe, which is something like

```
id    feat1    feat2  feat3    feat4
1      ...      ...   ...       ....
2      ...      ...   ...       ....
3      ...      ...   ...       ....
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
13689  a        b     c         d
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
14780  a        b     c         d
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
19848  a        b     c         d
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
22162  a        b     c         d
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
49923  a        b     c         d
```

My final goal is to have this

```
id    feat1    feat2  feat3    feat4
1      ...      ...   ...       ....
2      ...      ...   ...       ....
3      ...      ...   ...       ....
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
...    ...      ...   ...       ....
49923  a        b     c         d
```

(ps I don't care about id order or whatever, I just want to assign the same Id to the row with the same values).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert to graph and identify connected components

```
import networkx
g = networkx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "idA", "idB")
grps = [a for a in networkx.connected_components(g)]
print(grps)
# [{49923, 19848, 22162, 13689, 14780}, {2576, 47291, 23549, 28527}]
```

Comment: Thanks! It solves partially my problem but I think I can figure something out thanks to your solution. Thanks a lot!